# how to use scrapy to crawl all items in a website

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

i want to use recursion to crawl all the links in a website. and parse all the link pages, to extract all the detail links in the link pages.
if the page link confroms to a rule, the page link is a item i want to parse detail.
i use the code below:

```
class DmovieSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmovie"
    allowed_domains = ["movie.douban.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://movie.douban.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        item = DmovieItem()
        hxl = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls = hxl.select("//a/@href").extract()
        all_this_urls = []
        for url in urls:
            if re.search("movie.douban.com/subject/\d+/$",url):
                yield Request(url=url, cookies = cookies ,callback=self.parse_detail) 
            elif ("movie.douban.com" in url) and ("movie.douban.com/people" not in url) and ("movie.douban.com/celebrity" not in url) and ("comment" not in url):
                if ("update" not in url) and ("add" not in url) and ("trailer" not in url) and ("cinema" not in url) and (not redis_conn.sismember("crawledurls", url)):
                    all_this_urls.append(Request(url=url, cookies = cookies , callback=self.parse))
        redis_conn.sadd("crawledurls",response.url)
        for i in all_this_urls:
            yield i


    def parse_detail(self, response):
        hxl = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        title = hxl.select("//span[@property='v:itemreviewed']/text()").extract()
        title = select_first(title)
        img = hxl.select("//div[@class='grid-16-8 clearfix']//a[@class='nbgnbg']/img/@src").extract()
        img = select_first(img)
        info = hxl.select("//div[@class='grid-16-8 clearfix']//div[@id='info']")
        director = info.select("//a[@rel='v:directedBy']/text()").extract()
        director = select_first(director)
        actors = info.select("//a[@rel='v:starring']/text()").extract()
        m_type = info.select("//span[@property='v:genre']/text()").extract()
        release_date = info.select("//span[@property='v:initialReleaseDate']/text()").extract()
        release_date = select_first(release_date)

        d_rate = info.select("//strong[@class='ll rating_num']/text()").extract()
        d_rate = select_first(d_rate)

        info = select_first(info)
        post = hxl.select("//div[@class='grid-16-8 clearfix']//div[@class='related-info']/div[@id='link-report']").extract()
        post = select_first(post)
        movie_db = Movie()
        movie_db.name = title.encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.dis_time = release_date.encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.description = post.encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.actors = "::".join(actors).encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.director = director.encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.mtype = "::".join(m_type).encode("utf-8")
        movie_db.origin = "movie.douban.com"
        movie_db.d_rate = d_rate.encode("utf-8")
        exist_item =  Movie.where(origin_url=response.url).select().fetchone()
        if not exist_item:
            movie_db.origin_url = response.url
            movie_db.save()
            print "successed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

urls is all the links in the page.if one of the urls is the detail page i want to parse, yield a Request which callback method is parse_detail. else yield a request that callback method is parse.

in this way , i crawled some pages, but it seems that the pages is not full, at my result, it seems that some pages is not visited. could you tell me how ?is there some way to crawl all the pages correctly?

Comment: Please post all of your spider code. :)

Comment: @Talvalin code updated, thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try [CrawlSpider](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=CrawlSpider#crawlspider).

Use [crawling-rules](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=CrawlSpider#crawling-rules) to filter urls. ([demo](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#crawlspider-example))

And then set [DEPTH_LIMIT = 0](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#depth-limit) in the `settings.py` to make sure the spider crawls all pages in the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DmovieSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmovie"
    allowed_domains = ["movie.douban.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://movie.douban.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        req = []

        hxl = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls = hxl.select("//a/@href")

        for url in urls:
            r = Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail)
            req.append(r)

        return req

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        hxl = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        title = hxl.select("//span[@property='v:itemreviewed']/text()").extract()
        item = DmovieItem()
        item['title'] = title[0].strip()
        return item
```