# How to crawl each and every link given on a website and collect all the text using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I followed link

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254630/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-all-items-in-a-website`

but things does not work out for me.

I am trying to learn scraping data over web.I was implementing tutorial given on http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/examples.html

and able to crawl over  a given link 
here is sample code snap

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import Website


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        The lines below is a spider contract. For more info see:
        http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html

        @url http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/
        @scrapes name
        """
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

and Code snap for Item is

```
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class Website(Item):

    name = Field()
    description = Field()
    url = Field()
```

I am able to run crawler using `scrapy crawl dmoz`

but not able to achieve following thing

```
1. All given link on website
2. Didn't get all text from all possible link 
3. Want to save them to a file
```

Can some one guide me , for what changes need to do in my code so that i can achieve my objective ?

Answer (score 0):

1. All given link on website

   The response doesn't have `class="directory-url"` in it.
   You can get all given links from the website using `sites = sel.xpath('//a/@href')` instead of that. filter the  needed urls

   Or

   If you can start from the main domain (`http://www.dmoz.org/`),like

   `doc = html.fromstring(response.body)`
   `sites = doc.xpath('.//section[@id="category-section"]//aside')`

   `for site in sites:`
       `item = StackDemoItem()`
       `item['name'] = site.xpath('.//div/h2/a/text()')`
       `item['url'] = site.xpath('.//div/h2/a/@href')`

   you have to append the domain name with `item['url']` to get the proper url.Do the same for other pages respective of there url path.
2. Didn't get all text from all possible link

   Most of the links does't have text along with it. So you have to strip the contents from the url itself.else  `text = sel.xpath('//a/text()')`
3. Want to save them to a file

   You can simply save the contents using `scrapy crawl your_crawler_name -o out.csv` , use json or txt instead of csv for that kind of file.